# How to make advanced operations on SYS_REFCURSOR?

Tags: oracle

I have several procedures and functions that should make some computations on the same set of data (such that If I change the query of this set of data, the change will be reflected on all the other functions).

What I'm trying to do is creating a function that generates a SYS_REFCURSOR corresponding to the shared set of data.

For example :

```
MyTable : table(ID number, Amount number);
Type RefCursor** IS REF CURSOR RETURN MyTable%ROWTYPE;
```

The function that returns a cursor for the shared set of data :

```
function GetSharedSetOfData(SomeArgument varchar2) RETURN RefCursor is                
     Cur  RefCursor;
begin
    Open Cur for select * from MyTable where 
                        Condition1 and/or Condition2;
    return Cur;
end;
```

This function should be used in other functions like :

```
-- Function A
function Function_A_GetTheTotalOfAllRows return number is 
    Output number;
begin
    select sum(Amount) into Output from table(CAST(GetSharedSetOfData(SomeArgumentValue) as MyTable%rowtype));
    return Output;
end;

-- Function B
function Function_B_GetPartialTotalOfAllRows return number is 
    Output number;
begin
    select sum(Amount) into Output from table(CAST(GetSharedSetOfData(SomeArgumentValue) as MyTable%rowtype)) where ID < 100 ;
    return Output;
end;

-- Function C
function Function_C_GetOtherComputation return number is 
    Output number;
begin
    select sum(Amount) into Output from table(CAST(GetSharedSetOfData(SomeArgumentValue) as MyTable%rowtype)) where condition_Xx... ;
    return Output;
end;
```

The function GetSharedSetOfData compiles and work properly. However the following queries don't compile.

```
select sum(Amount) into Output from table(CAST(GetSharedSetOfData(SomeArgumentValue) as MyTable%rowtype));
```

I'm getting the error :

**ORA-00911: invalid character** it refers to the character '%' on **MyTable%rowtype**

Does anyone know how to do that please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Do you have to use a `sys_refcursor`?  It would seemingly make far more sense to use a view.  Or a pipelined table function.  Depending on things like whether you'd want the optimizer to be able to push the predicates from functions A-C to the SQL engine or whether you want to force the database to fetch every row every time even if you have a `where` clause on an indexed column that could be used to make the combined query much faster.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm trying to avoid pipelined table for performance reasons. I want the rows to be fecthed only when it's required. For the view I don't know how to created a view based on parameters. Do you have any idea how to create that please ?

Comment: "I want the rows to be fecthed only when it's required." What makes you think pipelined table function don't work that way?

Comment: "CAST(...as MyTable%rowtype)" - SQL and PL/SQL are different things. PL/SQL can understand SQL types, but SQL cannot understand PL/SQL types. By "SQL type" I mean a schema-level type that comes from a CREATE TYPE statement.

Comment: However, even if you use a "SQL type" it won't work. You need to say: select * from table(cast(MULTISET(<subquery>) as <schema level type>)) and the subquery needs to be written directly, not come from a REF CURSOR.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * From mytable;

        ID     AMOUNT
---------- ----------
      7369        800
      7566       2975
      7788       3000
```

Your first function:

```
SQL> create or replace function getsharedsetofdata(someargument varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor is
  3    cur  sys_refcursor;
  4  begin
  5      open cur for select * from mytable where 1 = 1;
  6      return cur;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.
```

Your second function (modified, quite a lot):

```
SQL> create or replace function Function_A
  2    return number is
  3    rc       sys_refcursor;
  4    l_id     mytable.id%type;
  5    l_amount mytable.amount%type;
  6    Output   number := 0;
  7  begin
  8      rc := getsharedsetofdata('a');
  9      loop
 10        fetch rc into l_id, l_amount;
 11        exit when rc%notfound;
 12        output := output + l_amount;
 13      end loop;
 14      return output;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT function_a from dual;

FUNCTION_A
----------
      6775

SQL>
```

---

As you can see, it *works*; see if you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It's hard to scale this function. I would like (if possible) to leverage on SQL engine to make the computations instead of fetching the ref cursor and make the computations manually. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you want to use a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  A `SYS_REFCURSOR` is simply a pointer to a cursor and the only thing you can do with a cursor is fetch data from it.  You say that you want to use the SQL engine rather than fetching all the data from the cursor and doing the computations in PL/SQL.  That is going to be inherently slower than the pipelined table function approach that you are trying to avoid because of performance issues (I'm assuming you have tested the pipelined table function approach and determined that it is too slow rather than just assuming).

One approach that would let you keep everything in SQL would be to define a context, define a view that uses the context, and replace the calls to `GetSharedSetOfData` with calls to set appropriate values in the context.  Something like this (not verified-- sites like livesql and dbfiddle don't let you create contexts so I don't have a playground to verify)

```
create or replace package my_pkg
as
  procedure set_ctx( p1 in number, p2 in number );
end;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg
as
  procedure set_ctx( p1 in number, p2 in number )
  as
  begin
    dbms_context.set_context( 'MY_CTX', 'P1', p1 );
    dbms_context.set_context( 'MY_CTX', 'P2', p2 );
  end set_ctx;
end my_pkg;
/

create or replace context my_ctx using my_pkg;
/

create or replace view my_view
as
select 1 id, 'foo' val
  from dual
 where sys_context( 'MY_CTX', 'P1' ) = 1
union all
select 2 id, 'bar' val
  from dual
 where sys_context( 'MY_CTX', 'P2' ) = 1
union all
select 3, 'foobar' 
  from dual;
/

create function funcA( p1 in number, p2 in number )
  return integer
as
  l_sum integer;
begin
  my_pkg.set_ctx( p1, p2 );

  select sum(id)
    into l_cnt
    from my_view
   where id < 3;

  return l_sum;
end;
```